# How does NetworkCredential in C# works when assigned to a HttpRequest object?

Tags: c#, httprequest, networkcredentials

I want to know how NetworkCredentials are passed over an http request. Do they get passed as HTTPHeaders, RequestData or there is something else that carries the information.

I tried creating a sample app and checked the fiddler logs. I don't see it being added as HTTPHeader so what carries that information.

Here is the sample code I tried:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://gmail.com");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("TestUser", "Password-1");
```

Comment: Depends on the type of authentication you request. `Credentials` is just the placeholder for the credentials. What kind of authentication do you want to perform?

Comment: BTW *Gmail* doesn't use usernames and passwords. You have to authenticate to *google* first using OAuth

Answer (score 0):

From the following MSDN page;

> Supported authentication schemes include Digest, Negotiate, Kerberos,
>   NTLM, and Basic.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx

So it will depend, usually I guess it will pick the most secure and available method... However it also says;

> To restrict HttpWebRequest to one or more authentication methods, use
>   the CredentialCache class and bind your credentials to one or more
>   authentication schemes

So if you wished it to be used as headers I suppose you could restrict it to only using Basic authentication using the CredentialCache object;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache(v=vs.110).aspx